# Need a good Logging Library with custom tags and filter ability

Tags: java, logging

I would like to write a GUI application that has a big control in it that displays output of logging.

It would have a dropdown menu to filter it.

So therefore I need to find a Logging library for java that allows me to:

1. Create a custom class to interface with the output, so that i can redirect it to my GUI control
2. Allow me to assign a custom tag to what I am logging...

   e.g. log("abc", "it's tuesday")

   e.g. log("def", "it's 2013")

   e.g. log("ghi", "logging is tedious")
3. This is optional but I really would like it... ability to filter based on multiple of these tags... e.g. show output of "abc" and "def" but not "ghi"

Any suggestions? and, if you can, please list any other reasons the suggest library is good to use.

thanks.

Comment: I'd, personally, take a look at `Log4j`, it allows you to define your own appenders. While it won't let you define your own tags, you could tag the message directly and have you output view strip this from the display

Comment: This post may be closed for being off-topic soon. That said, I've had good experiences with log4j in the past.

Comment: I think a little twist in the way he is asking can bring this question in-topic again.  Honestly I do think this question is ok, especially he described a tagging scenario.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Slf4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) + [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/). Slf4j is an abstract logging API that is used by many (if not the most) OS projects and Logback is IMHO the best logging implementation.

Slf4J supports [Markers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165558/best-practices-for-using-markers-in-slf4j-logback), that you can use to tag your logging output.

Logback supports advanced filtering configuration: http://logback.qos.ch/manual/filters.html.

You can create your own [Appender](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html) to send data to any output source.

In general you can use hierarchy of loggers (e.g. org.myapp.abc, org.myapp.performance etc.) to organize your output as well.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in combination of SLF4J + Logback

1. You can create an custom appender for such purpose.  I even remember someone has developed similar GUI that you can make use of already
2. Markers in SLF4J seems a good candidate to perform your "tagging"
3. Yes, SLF4J + Logback do allow you to filter base on markers attached in a log event

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much code you are willing to write you can do this with java SE logger:

[Custom Log Level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12089902/custom-log-level)

You can simple create loggers of the required tpye and use them and for the other functionalities use regex-patterns.

This is not the easiest way but you may have all the controll you need.